# Which event used in jquery when textbox value get changed using code not by manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing a application in MVC.

I have a view which contain another partial view.

I have textbox1 in a parent view but its value get assigned from partial view.

Now, the moment the Textbox1 get assigned with some value, I want to perform some action
like put the 10% value textbox1 value on the another textbox, textbox2 of the view.

( I want the event when textbox value get changed by code, not the manual entry.
so cant use blur() event. )

which event in jquery should I used to perform this task ?

Comment: trigger the event while changing using code... using `.trigger('change')` or `.change()`

Comment: No, these events occurs when we put value in textbox manually.

Comment: Why don't you add your logic right after you change the value in your code then?

Comment: Cant get change event when value is set programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

Partials views are all processed server-side, where Javascript is not executed. Javascript only works with the full page and does not know anything about partials, so take this worry out of your question.

As already been mentioned, you need [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and if that is not good enough, just create a function that updates value of your checkbox and do other stuff which you need doing.

```
//psudo-code using .trigger()
function updateTextbox(value){
   $('#myTexboxId').val(value);
   $('#myTexboxId').trigger('change');
}
```

And here another method where you create another function that updates your values and does the calculation for you.

```
//pseudo-code using another function
function updateMyTextbox(value){
   $('#myTextboxId').val(value);
   doCalculation();
}

$('#myTextBoxId').on('change',function(){
    doCalculation();
});

function doCalculation(){
// update your other values
}
```

Comment: problem is , I am not getting the event which should fire when textbox value gets changed automatically ( Depends on some calculations) . Not when we put values manually.

Comment: Yes, that's why people did mention `.trigger()` for you. Please see code samples.